# Horizontal line in microsoft word 2007 acting strangely and hard to remove?

Tags: microsoft-word

I was writing a document in Word and used shift + underline continuously to make a horizontal line dividing 2 separate parts of the text. When I press enter, it automatically got changed to a thick dark horizontal line. It worked fine as a divider.

But then I discovered, when I went to edit the document, the text can be changed, but most of the time, the divider line itself cannot be removed, unless I delete absolutely everything.

It looks like this:

[image: Text above and below line]

If I try to delete the line using backspace with the cursor at the start of the line of text under the divider where it says "below line", it only moves the text to the end of the previous line as if the horizontal dividing line is not there at all, like this:

[image: Delete using backspace]

If there are multiple text lines above the divider line, attempting to delete it using the delete button with the cursor at the end of the line directly above the divider (previous example would be the line that says "above line"), it just brings the line of text below the divider up next to it, as if the divider is not there.

Then, I can no longer move that line of text back to being below the divider where it belongs by pressing 'enter'.

[image: Multiple lines of text]

In this example, if I try to delete the divider by putting the cursor on the right side of the number 6 and pressing 'delete', it only moves 7 next to it above the divider so it looks like this:

[image: line 7 moves up a line]

It seems the only way to remove it is to actually delete 100% of the text above it, which means if there is only 1 line of text above the divider, it will work. Otherwise, if there are pages of text, all of it needs to go for the divider to go too.

If I try and 'cheat' by highlighting and cutting all the lines of text except the one immediately above the divider, then deleting the last remaining line, the divider disappears but comes back in a random place higher up than where it used to be when I paste the text back (even if the divider line was not included in the highlighting).

The divider refuses to go unless there is no text above it.

What is this, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word automatically formats items like quotes, bulleted and numbered lists, and horizontal lines. When you type at least three dashes, underscores, or equal signs in a paragraph by themselves and press Enter, the characters are automatically converted to a single, thick single, or double horizontal line, respectively.

To remove one such line, the simplest method is to immediately press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the change.

If you notice the change too late to undo, you may remove it as follows :

- Place the cursor in the paragraph just above where the line was added
- Click the *Home* tab on the ribbon
- In the *Paragraph* section, click the down arrow on the right side of the
  Borders button and select "No Border".

If you wish to disable this option permanently, you may remove it as follows :

- Click the *File* tab and choose *Options*
- Click *Proofing* on the left
- Click the *AutoCorrect Options...* button
- Click the *AutoFormat As You Type* tab
- In the *Apply as you type* section, uncheck *Border lines*
- Click OK twice.

[image]

For more detailed instructions with screenshots see the article
[How to Remove Automatic Horizontal Lines in Word](https://www.howtogeek.com/217924/how-to-remove-automatic-horizontal-lines-in-word/).

Comment: Thanks! I knew it got auto formatted, but not to what. This did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

#### When I press enter, it automatically got changed to a thick dark horizontal line

Word has converted your line into a paragraph border.

To remove it:

- Click in the paragraph above the line.
- Menu > Format > Borders and Shading and click "None".

Source [Deleting lines made with Shift-underline - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/deleting-lines-made-with-shift-underline/9dd6729d-68fe-4d7d-ba30-23cf25e73652?db=5)